# Golang: extract data with Regex

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, go

I'm trying to extract whatever data inside `${}`.

For example, the data extracted from this string should be `abc`.

```
git commit -m '${abc}'
```

Here is the actual code:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("${*}")
match := re.FindStringSubmatch(command)
```

But that doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In regex, `$`, `{` and `}` have special meaning

```
$ <-- End of string
{} <-- Contains the range. e.g. a{1,2}
```

So you need to escape them in the regex. Because of things like this, it is best to use [raw string literals](https://go101.org/article/basic-types-and-value-literals.html#string-literals) when working with regular expressions:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\$\{([^}]*)\}`)
match := re.FindStringSubmatch("git commit -m '${abc}'")
fmt.Println(match[1])
```

**[Golang Demo](https://go.dev/play/p/8U-MP0hk8hu)**

With double quotes (interpreted string literals) you need to also escape the backslashes:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}")
```

Comment: A hint: using raw string literals to define a regex pattern is advisable. E.g. [`re := regexp.MustCompile(\`\$\{(.*?)\}\`)`](https://play.golang.org/p/jK5TSUGCxt)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its already in another answer..so i didn't updated mine

Comment: The other answer is not correct, I think. `+?` and `*?` are different quantifiers. In regex, every symbol matters and can change the output greatly.

Answer (score 4):

Try re := `regexp.MustCompile(\$\{(.*)\})`
* is a quantifier, you need something to quantify. `.` would do as it matches everything.

Comment: `.*` is a greedy subpattern and can overfire. Use with caution. It might work only with the current example, but not in real life scenario.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't, he wanted to know why his expression didn't work, I told him why.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this too,

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}")

str := "git commit -m '${abc}'"
res := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, 1)
for i := range res {
    //like Java: match.group(1)
    fmt.Println("Message :", res[i][1])
}
```

GoPlay: https://play.golang.org/p/PFH2oDzNIEi

Answer (score 1):

For another approach, you can use `os.Expand`:

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   command := "git commit -m '${abc}'"
   var match string
   os.Expand(command, func(s string) string {
      match = s
      return ""
   })
   println(match == "abc")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#Expand

Answer (score 0):

Because `$`, `{` and `}` all have special meaning in a regex and need to be backslashed to match those literal characters, because `*` doesn't work that way, and because you didn't actually include a capturing group for the data you want to capture. Try:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\$\{.+?)\}`)
```

Comment: The `*` in the OP pattern makes me think that the string inside `{}` can be empty. Thus, rock's answer seems to be closer to what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named group to extract the value of a string.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    command := "git commit -m '${abc}'"

    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\$\{(?P<text>\w+)\}`)
    subMatch := r.FindStringSubmatch(command)

    fmt.Printf("text : %s", subMatch[1])
}
```

<kbd>[**GoPlay**](https://go.dev/play/p/Pt-lJRQQZte)</kbd>